# Join data from two tables via another table, postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join

So, i'm fighting with that, can't find the solution. Here's problem:
We have three tables. The first one is connected to second by id, the third is connected to second as well by id, and there's no connection between first an third.

[image]

I need to join `name` from first and sum of `id` from third table.
i tried to use subqueries, but failed to organize joining.

Any suggestions?

Comment: JOIN is not just a word here use join instead of subqueries

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a three-level category problem. This might help you

```
select Tab1.name, sum(Tab3.id)
from Tab1
join Tab2
on Tab1.id = Tab2.tab1_id
join Tab3
on Tab2.id = Tab3.tab2_id
group by Tab1.id
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In a three table join query, you could something like this:

```
    SELECT tab1.name, COUNT(tab3.id) AS sum_ids 
    FROM tab1 INNER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id=tab2.tab1_id 
    INNER JOIN tab3 ON tab2.id=tab3.tab2_id GROUP BY tab1.id;
```

Comment: Why should he use an inner join?

Comment: @LajosArpad here is the reason: Use an inner join when you want only the results that appear in both tables that match the Join condition.